# Binding ItemsSource to an XML String

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xmldataprovider

I have a database stored procedure call that, among other columns, returns a column that contains data in XML format. I'm trying to display the results of this call in a grid (the call is made through Entity Framework, so the actual objects bound to the grid are POCO's, and the column in question is a `string` property).

While the normal columns display correctly, I need to be able to take the XML data in that one column and bind its contents (it will contain multiple nodes) to an `ItemsControl` within the template for the cell.

For example, let's say I have a grid that displays a collection of the following object:

```
class Photo
{
    string PhotoId { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string TagListXml { get; set; }
}
```

This is intended to represent a photo, and the `TagListXml` property contains an XML string listing all of the tags that have been applied to the photo. Something akin to...

```
<PhotoTags>
    <Tag>Faces</Tag>
    <Tag>People</Tag>
    <Tag>Sepia</Tag>
</PhotoTags>
```

(While obviously a normal POCO would have a `List<string>` or something like that, let's just assume for the moment that I must use an XML string)

In my grid, I want to be able to specify an `ItemsControl` that uses this XML and, ultimately, gives me items `Faces`, `People`, and `Sepia`.

I've tried this for a cell template:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TagListXml, 
                                Converter={StaticResource xmlConverter}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Where `xmlConverter` is defined as such:

```
<dc:StringToXmlConverter x:Key="xmlConverter" XPath="PhotoTags" />
```

And `dc:StringToXmlConverter` is a custom `IValueConverter` that just takes a string value, instantiates an `XmlDocument` and loads the string, then returns an `XmlDataProvider` with that new document and the `XPath` specified above.

While this does not produce any errors either in the form of an exception or a binding error in the Output window, it doesn't *do* anything (there are no results displayed).

I believe this is because an `XmlDataProvider` cannot be set to the `ItemsSource` directly, but rather must be set as the `Source` of a `Binding`. (in other words, you must do `ItemSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlProvider}}"` rather than `ItemsSource="{StaticResource xmlProvider}"`).

I can't seem to get anywhere with it, and I've been banging my head on this for the last couple of hours.

**How can I bind an XML string to the `ItemsSource` of an `ItemsControl`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not return an `XmlNode[]` instead of a `XmlDataProvider` (which is mainly for XAML anyway)?

Comment: Well, don't I feel a bit stupid. I suppose the honest answer to that would be "Because it didn't occur to me". You'll get the tickmark as soon as the timer expires. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamRobinson: Overlooking the most simple solutions happens quite often :P